# SDL2 w/ CMake FetchContent and MinGW

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, sdl

I'm trying to make a SDL2 project in C++, which I've managed to get working using Clang++, I would just like a better way to receiving SDL2 libraries, and CMake seems like a good option here, with it's FetchContent feature. I first build with the MinGW Makefiles option, `cmake -B build -G "MinGW Makefiles`, and then then try to run `make`, but I get this error:

```
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: _deps/sdl2-build/libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.c.obj):SDL_windows_ma:(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `SDL_main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\chip8.dir\build.make:152: chip8.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:136: CMakeFiles/chip8.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [makefile:120: all] Error 2
```

My Windows build system looks as follows:

```
# FetchContent SDL2, SDL2_ttf
include(FetchContent)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET NO)

set(SDL2_VERSION 2.30)
FetchContent_Declare(
    SDL2
    GIT_REPOSITORY      https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL
    GIT_TAG             release-2.30.0
    OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2)
include_directories(${SDL2_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2::SDL2main SDL2::SDL2-static)
```

For more details, here is the github page (it has sdl2_ttf stuff currently commented, to get SDL2 working first)

https://github.com/Naginipython/Chip8_Emulator

Comment: This means one of two things. Either the signature of `main` is wrong (not your case, you correctly have `int main(int, char**)`, SDL2 on Windows doesn't like anything else). Or the file where you have `main()` doesn't include `SDL_main.h` (or just `SDL.h`) (which on Windows contains `#define main SDL_main`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Just saying, if I guessed correctly, then the duplicate is wrong because it doesn't have this answer (about a missing include).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: "...the duplicate is wrong because it doesn't have this answer (about a missing include)" - Well, it seems to be a case: https://github.com/Naginipython/Chip8_Emulator/blob/master/src/main.cpp. However, that "wrong" could be fixed just by adding a corresponding answer to the duplicate. In the current form, the details **in question post** (not under the link) are superseded by ones in the duplicate, that is why I create the "duplicate" relationship.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Can you tell me more about this `#define main SDL_main`? In window.h, I have `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED \n #include <SDL2/SDL.h>` prior to using SDL functions, is there more that I am missing? Am I using a wrong path here to the include using CMake?

Comment: Remove `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED`.